# Is there a way to invert the QWidget::setMask() function or achieve similar effect?

Tags: c++, qt, mask

I'm trying to "cut a hole" in my widgets background so that it's at a specif location totally transparent and that you you can see what is behind it. The problem is that the neither the size or the location of this "hole" are fixed, so it can basically be anywhere on the widget so that's why I can't use mask images.

There is the function setMask(QRegion) but the effect that I require would need to be inverted, so basically instead of only drawing the masked region it should be drawing all that is not covered by the mask.

Is there a way to achieve such effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, with @ilotXXI help I've figured out a way which seems to be better then setting the widget mask:

```
if(mouseIsDown)                    // Only draw empty rect when mouse down
    painter.setClipRegion(rectRegion.subtracted(emptyRegion));

painter.setBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0, 150));  //color for not-empty area
painter.drawRect(this->geometry());      // draw not-empty area
```

This seems to work much faster then setting the mask and I have no lag anymore. @ilotXXI thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
const QRegion emptyRegion = <create your region>;
const QRegion rectRegion(QRect(QPoint(), widget->size()));
widget->setMask(rectRegion.subtracted(emptyRegion));
```

Comment: Awesome, this works. Though it's kind of slow, it's lagging a bit. Any why to improve the speed or cache something?

Comment: I don't know. When does it lag? At first, when do you apply it?

Comment: The empty region is drawn via mouse so it lags when I'm drawing this region. 

I take the mouseDown location and on mouseMove update current mouse location and base on that I get the emptyRegion. In the mouseMove function I also call Update() to draw the widget again and in the overwritten paintEvent I apply the mask.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I made a mistake. Possibly `... rectRegion(QRect(QPoint(), widget->size())` should be used in 2nd line.

Comment: You shouldn't do it on each `paintEvent`. It is called with any reason, even when OS is bored. So, you want to drag this "hole" by mouse when button is pressed?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, in the paintEvernt I'm checking if the user is currently drawing and only in that case I draw the stuff, otherwise it's ignored.

What it does is when the user presses and holds down left mouse button it draws a rectangle which is transparent, that is the idea.

Comment: @dporobic Re-evaluate and apply the mask only on `mouseDownEvent` and `mouseMoveEvent` (when left button is pressed). When user changes draw mode, you should `clearMask` or apply it with new region, depending on new mode. This prevents extra intensive mask applying in `paintEvent`s. P.S.: does `rectRegion(QRect(QPoint(), widget->size())` work? It's better to correct the answer in this case.

Comment: Can't see much of a difference between `rectRegion(widget->geometry())` and `rectRegion(QRect(QPoint(), widget->size())`, seems to be behaving the same. 

I have moved now the setting mask into the MouseMove function and cleaned a bit up, seem to be working fine now. There is still some small lag but this could be just coming from the composer that is handling my desktop graphics.